# Panning an image with head motion on Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is there any solution for panning images using head motion?  i.e. the ['Meet the Team' easter egg](http://techcrunch.com/video/google-glass-meet-the-team-easter-egg/517757589/).  Works very well on the easter egg!

Would be great to have this in the GDK (hint hint Google). I have [found this library](https://github.com/lnanek/GyroImageView) which works for horizontal panning and I will likely just adapt this if there is not another solution out there.

Comment: I'm in need of implementing the same use case for panning an  image left and right. I tried the one below suggested Tony Allevato solution, i couldn't achieve the image panning while moving my head towards left or right on google glass. Let me suggest the solution to achieve the image panning on head motion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any solution right now would involve listening to the sensors manually and then translating the visible region of the view based on those values. It sounds like the component you linked does most, if not all, of what you need.

If you would like to see such a feature included as a public GDK API, feel free to file a feature request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list)!

Comment: Think there may be a lot of apps using this type of function.  Would be nice to have a solid implemenation out of the box in the GDK.

Comment: Feature request here - star if you want this! https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=379&thanks=379&ts=1390680867

Answer (score 4):

I implemented something like this. Maybe you want to test it: https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/Head%20Image%20View

Comment: thanks for the link I will try it out.  FYI the issue has been accepted by GDK so there will be an official implementation at some point.

Comment: @pscholl I'm trying to use your implementation, but when I am using it with image of the same size you have it scales down to size of the screen so no panning when I move my head.

Comment: it defaults to a scale factor of 1, so no zoom at all. At some point you need to call the setScaleFactor() with something larger than that. Or change the default value at HeadImageView.java:17.

Comment: @pscholl yes that made it.

Comment: @pscholl , i tried the code you suggested, i couldn't noticed the image panning on head motion while moving left or right.the image i provided completely fitted on my screen.let me suggest an solution to make the image panning on head motion.

Comment: you need to call setScaleFactor() with something larger than 1., otherwise the image will just be scaled to fit the screen.